# play and reverse GSAP animation on click using javascript, not jQuery

Tags: javascript, animation, gsap

I have created the following GSAP animation and i want to make it run when i click on the svg element and reversed when i click again. I don't want to use jQuery.

```
var svg = document.getElementsByTagName("svg"),
tl = new TimelineMax();

tl.fromTo("#path1", 1,{drawSVG:"0% 25%"}, {drawSVG:"30% 100%", delay:3})
 .to("#path1", .8,{drawSVG:"63% 100%"}, "-=0.15")
 .to("#pathLine1", .8, {x:10 , y:5 ,   opacity:0 , ease:Power1.ease}, "-=1.4")
 .to("#pathLine2", .8, {x:-10 , y:5 ,   opacity:0 , ease:Power1.ease}, "-=1.4");
```

Here is the codepen link

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bwpbBV

i tried adding this after my timeline code but it doesn't work

```
svg.onclick = function() {
 tl.reversed() ? tl.play() : tl.reverse();
}
```

Cheers

Comment: `getElementsByTagName()` returns an array-like collection of elements, not an individual element. Try `svg[0].onclick`. If you have multiple <svg> elements that you want to be clickable you need to manually add the click handler to all of them.

Comment: Or use [event delegation](http://javascript.info/tutorial/event-delegation) and add the listener to the parent of all SVGs.

Comment: Thank you for that. I've added {paused:true} as an initial parameter and then i added svg[0].onclick = function() {
    tl.paused(false);
} and the animation started when i clicked. Now i have to find how to reverse the animation on the second click. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you want to toggle the direction of the playhead, in your onclick you should be able to just do tl.reversed( !tl.reversed() ); but remember to call reverse() initially on the timeline so that on the first click, it toggles forward instead of backward.

Comment: @Jack Man, that was awesome, it works now. I first added `reversed:false` as a parameter in the timeline and then i added `tl.reversed( !tl.reversed() ); ` inside the onclick function. Thanks a lot, this was really helpful.